# How record Qt Widgets StyleSheet in a sepatated file

Tags: qt, widget, stylesheet, qtwidgets

Is it possible to get the stylesheet from a separated file for a Qt Widgets application, like .CSS does to .HTML ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You may load any file with `QFile` and use `setStyleSheet` method in your application or any widget.

Comment: Instead of using QFile and load via C++, isn't possible to add a reference in .ui files?

Comment: It is possible to directly modify QSS for each widget in .ui files. See `styleSheet` property. But if you want to load QSS from your files - you should implement your own logic. Because Qt is a framework, but not a magicwand, that knows what you want to achieve.

Comment: Btw, what is a problem with loading a file? It is a couple lines of code: `widget->setStyleSheet( file->readAll() );`

Comment: not a problem after all. Just wanna know if there is something like HTML and CSS. read a file like this can solve the problem !

Comment: QSS doesn't support any "include" directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You may load any file with QFile and use setStyleSheet method in your application or any widget. by @SaZ